# Implementing SendBatchAsync for Microsoft Azure Service Bus Brokered Messages

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, azureservicebus, brokeredmessage

My requirement is that I have to send a list of brokered messages to the azure service bus asynchronously. However I am not able to implement the **SendBatchAsync** method properly. Let me explain in detail. Here is my code:

```
public async Task SendBatchEnrollmentMessages()
{
    while(somevalue) 
    {
        //logic to fetch data from the SQL db through stored proc into list of brokered message i.e. messageList
        if(messageList.Count() > 0)
        {
            await sender.SendMessagesAsync(messageList);
        } 
        //some more logic for somevalue
    }
}
```

where the SendMessageAsync logic is :

```
public async Task SendMessagesAsync(List<BrokeredMessage> brokeredMessageList)
{
    var topicClient = CreateTopicClient();
    await topicClient.SendBatchAsync(brokeredMessageList);
}
```

My issue is that when I debug the application using break point, the compiler comes till `await topicClient.SendBatchAsync(brokeredMessageList);` and exits the code i.e application debuggin is completed. It doesn't return back to the  while condition. However instead of using **SendBatchAsync** if I use **SendBatch**, it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

**Solution:** The issue was with the test method which was calling the above funciton. It was of type void. It should have been of type async Task. A big thanks to **Ned Stoyanov** for helping me out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `async` method returns when after encounters an `await` statement and sets up the asynchronous operation being awaited. The rest of the method then continues after the `await` is finished.

You probably can't step through `async` methods like that, but try putting a breakpoint after the `await` and it should get hit when the asynchronous call completes.

Alternatively you may have a deadlock, see this [post](http://www.nedstoyanov.com/async-await-deadlock/) for some ways to avoid it.

As mentioned in our discussion the unit test needs to be `async` as well, return  a `Task` and `await` any `async` calls

```
[TestMethod] 
public async Task SendRegionsEnrollmentMessages() 
{ 
    EventManager eventMgr = new EventManager(clientUrn, programUrn, "CW"); 
    await eventMgr.SendBatchEvents(EventType.ENROLLMENT); 
}
```

Comment: Pls see my update in the question. As you rightly suggested this has to be due to await operator.  However I need it to return to the while condition because I have to send more brokered messages as batches. But that is not happening. The code execution just stops. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: is there any exceptions being thrown? Or maybe `messageList.Count()` is 0?

Comment: No exception is thrown and the count is also not 0. When the compiler comes to that line, the code execution just stops i.e. it does not even go to the } at the end..

Comment: the code you posted looks good, but maybe you have a deadlock, try replacing `await topicClient.SendBatchAsync(brokeredMessageList)` with `await topicClient.SendBatchAsync(brokeredMessageList).ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: Same thing is happening i.e. the compiler is still coming to that line and exiting.

Comment: Try changing the line `await topicClient.SendBatchAsync(brokeredMessageList);` to `await Task.Delay(5000);` and see what happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79527/discussion-between-nitinvertigo-and-ned-stoyanov).